# Change only one value of an array returned by sql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a payment schedule table where I pull data from the database. The query result fetches four records because there are four payment plans in my table. The code below works fine. The only change I need is here

```
  <td align="left" style="padding-left:5px;">
    <?php  echo $rr['plan_duration']?>
  </td>
```

**I am struggling to put an `IF` condition for the echo statement** I want to see the contents of the array first and then decide what to echo. If the value of `$rr['plan_duration']` is 1490 then echo 149 else echo the actual value of `$rr['plan_duration']` I am facing issues with mixing html with php as far as the syntax is concerned. Please help me implement this condition. Thanks.

Here is the full working code:

```
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * from memship_plan where status='1' order by plan_amount DESC");
while($rr=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
?>                                    
<tr height="30px">
  <td align="left" style="padding-left:5px;" class="red_text">
    <?php  echo $rr['plan_name']?>
  </td>
  <td align="left" style="padding-left:5px;">
    <?php  echo $rr['plan_contacts']?>
  </td>
  <td align="left" style="padding-left:5px;">
    Unlimited
  </td>
  <td align="left" style="padding-left:5px;">
    <?php  echo $rr['video']?>
  </td>
  <td align="left" style="padding-left:5px;">
    <?php  echo $rr['plan_duration']?>
  </td>
  <td align="left" style="padding-left:5px;">
    Rs. 
    <?php echo $rr['plan_amount']?>
  </td>
  <td align="left" style="padding-left:5px;">
    <a href="pay.php?plan=<?php echo $rr['plan_name']?>">Pay Now
    </a>
  </td>
</tr>
```

PS: I understand the limitation and disadvantages of mysql and I am going to covert it to mysqli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rewrote your code a bit to make it a bit better to read. I added a shorthand if statement. Take a look:

```
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * from memship_plan where status='1' order by plan_amount DESC");

$results = array();
while($record = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $results[] = $record;
}
?>

<?php foreach ($results as $rr): ?>
<tr height="30px">
    <td align="left" style="padding-left:5px;" class="red_text"><?= $rr['plan_name']; ?></td>
    <td align="left" style="padding-left:5px;"><?=  $rr['plan_contacts']; ?></td>
    <td align="left" style="padding-left:5px;">Unlimited</td>
    <td align="left" style="padding-left:5px;"><?= $rr['video']; ?></td>
    <td align="left" style="padding-left:5px;"><?= ($rr['plan_duration'] == '1490') ? '149' : $rr['plan_duration']; ?></td>
    <td align="left" style="padding-left:5px;">Rs. <?= $rr['plan_amount']; ?></td>
    <td align="left" style="padding-left:5px;"><a href="pay.php?plan=<?php echo $rr['plan_name']?>">Pay Now</a></td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Inside your `while` loop you can just use an `if statement`.

```
<td align="left" style="padding-left:5px;">
    <?php  if  ($rr['plan_duration'] == 1490) {
        echo 149 ;
    } else {
        echo $rr['plan_duration'];
    } ?>
</td>
```

Comment: Thanks. appreciate your efforts !

Answer (score 2):

You can insert an entire PHP block inside each `td` element. Create a function that does the converting from 1490 to 149, let's call it `convert()` in this example

```
<td align="left" style="padding-left:5px;">
    <?php
        if($rr['plan_duration'] == 1490)
        {
            echo convert($rr['plan_duration'])  
        }
        else
        {
            echo $rr['plan_duration'];
        }
    ?>
</td>
```

You can also use the `?` conditional to reduce the amount of code:

```
<td align="left" style="padding-left:5px;">
     <?php echo ($rr['plan_duration'] == 1490) ? convert($rr['plan_duration']) : $rr['plan_duration'];
</td>
```

**Note**: Besides using `mysqli` instead of `mysql` I strongly advice you to use Prepared Statements too

Comment: Thanks. I liked the `?` condition to reduce code lines and easy understanding

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * from memship_plan where status='1' order by plan_amount DESC");
while($rr=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
?>
<td align="left" style="padding-left:5px;">
    <?php  if($rr['plan_duration']=='1490') {
        echo "149";
    } else {
        echo $rr['plan_duration'];
    }
    ?>
</td>
<?php } ?>
```